# File gets uploaded despite limit being set, input not getting emptied

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm probably missing something obvious but once I confirm the ok in the `window.alert` the file name still appears next to `Choose File`? So it's being uploaded to the input still. How do I prevent this?

```
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" onChange={chooseFile} />
```

```
  const chooseFile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    if (file.size > 2e6) {
      window.alert("Please upload a file smaller than 2 MB")
      e.target.file = ""
      return false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty the `value` property of the `input`. For that change `e.target.file = ""` to `e.target.value = ""`. Here is your hole code:

```
const chooseFile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    if (file.size > 2e6) {
      window.alert("Please upload a file smaller than 2 MB")
      e.target.value = ""
      return false
    }
  }
```